# printf method and the Scanner class

Tags: java

I recently wrote a program in which I had to use dialog boxes to capture input and output information. Here's one of the statements:

```
packageType = 
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Enter the customer's package (A,B, or C): ");
```

I now have to write it again but use the printf method instead. I tried writing it this way:

```
System.out.printf("Enter the customer's package (A, B, or C): %-10s",
packageType = input.nextLine());
```

I can't get it to work and I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. I'm new to Java and I appreciate the help.

Comment: are you really passing `packageType = input.nextLine()` as parameter to `System.out.printf`?

Comment: Yes, I 'm trying to figure out a way to get the input and pass it to packageType so I can use it again in the program.

Comment: System.out.printf is going to block, waiting for input.nextLine() to complete before it prints out your prompt.  What you need to do is issue the prompt (System.out.printf), followed by reading from System.in.

Comment: So System.in should be the argument for (System.out.printf)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to Java myself, but it looks like an easy way to do it would be:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println ("Enter the customer's package type: A, B, or C:");
packageType = input.nextLine();
System.out.printf ("The customer's package type is %s.", packageType);
```

System.out.printf is only for outputting text.  It lets you format it in different ways, but it's not used for capturing input.  This example doesn't really do a whole lot of formatting (it's only a letter).

I hope this helps.

Jim

Comment: That's what I was thinking but my assignment says: The input/output must be done using System.out.printf() to get credit (DO NOT use the System.out.println() or System.out.print() methods. I'm baffled! Thanks for you input. Maxx

Comment: Hi Maxx, 
Sorry I didn't see this earlier.  As far as I know, printf is really used for output - formatting of text, numbers, etc.  You can accept input after a printf output by sending the user's input to System.in.
I'm not sure what benefit there is to using System.out.printf before the user's input, however.
Good luck!

Comment: No worries, I found out that you can use the pritnf just like println and print. You just don't need the last parameter. like so:                               
  System.out.printf("Enter the number of hours used: ");
  int hours;
  hours = keyboard.nextInt();

Comment: 'System.out.printf("Enter the number used:");'                                               'int hours = keyboard.next.Int( );'

Answer (score 0):

The printf can work like the print and println if you don't include the second parameter: `System.out.printf("String", notInclude);` So code it this way to pass input:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.printf("Enter the customer's package type: A, B, or C:");
String packageLetter = input.nextLine();
```